# How to call a kotlin function from gradle in android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In my android project, I have a kotlin object `AssetValidator` which does some validation over the asset files.

```
object AssetValidator {

    fun validate(assetsDir: File) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Until now, I was calling this function at the startup of my application. But now, I am thinking of  calling it from build script instead. But, I am unable to import this package into my gradle file. Android studio is showing `Unresolved reference` in the import statement. Someone please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Do you want to call it both from the application and from the build script, or only from the build script? And does it use some classes/methods from the application?

Comment: I want to only call it from build script, since it just validates some asset files. But yes, it uses some data classes from application and also it uses a dependency for loading webp images.